# How to get filename value from an array in node js

Tags: node.js

how get filename from below array in node js

[ { fieldname: 'image',
    originalname: 'download.jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: './upload',
    filename: 'image-1565956309906.jpeg',
    path: 'upload/image-1565956309906.jpeg',
    size: 15949 } ]

Comment: array[0].filename

Comment: You should read the basic documentation of Javascript from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

Use a destructuring assignment

```
const [filename] = array;
```

Using numeric array accessors is ugly and not always useful. You can then just use 'filename'

```
console.log(filename) //image-1565956309906.jpeg
```

Start reading the specification.